# Cross-platform C/C++ libraries with examples for raw audio record and playback

Tags: c++, c, audio, cross-platform

I'm developing a note-taking utility and want to add a feature for voice-recording and playback in full duplex asynchronous mode.
What cross-platform c/c++ libraries/API's can I evaluate for my purpose? Google isn't much help in this case and the existing QA's on SO doesn't quite cover this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) can accomplish what you want. It has lots of backends for different technologies like ALSA, ASIO, DirectSound etc.

Comment: OK, just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151278/cross-platform-sound-api - looks like the ticket :)

Comment: Also, if you don't care about Windows: most modern Unix-like systems have a port of Linux's Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JUCE](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php). Has lots of audio helpers and numerous other utilities that make for fast development.

Comment: Didn't know about this so downloaded the latest zip (2.0) and compiled 'JuceDemo' (I'm on Debian), and this is impressive. I'm certainly going to give this a serious go ..

Comment: OK, I tried to get juce set up for use in codeblocks, but couldn't get it to compile anything. I had a look at the source and got the impression it is approaching 'spaghetti-monster'-status, although I'll try to extract usable snippets from the code, I'm not any more going to waste much time with it.