# Continuous warning sound in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

What is the easiest way to play a continuous warning sound that lasts several minutes without affecting the main thread's performance?
I know that QSound can work in asynchronous mode, however, according to here:
[Qt: How to play sound witout blocking main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600515/qt-how-to-play-sound-witout-blocking-main-thread)
QSound would still bring noticeable affect on the main thread.

Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: Have you actually noticed such an impact on the main thread of your  app or you're just curious? :) Actually the link, you've provided, is of 2011, so Qt could overcome those difficulties by now

Comment: Currently no. But if I put in too much asynchronous operation, will the main thread's performance be affected?

Comment: definitely, yes. But it needs testing for particular operations, I guess. This can be undetectable, like when you draw your app's window there are many operations done in the main thread, but you hardly can notice this

Comment: So the best choice is to put the sounding in another thread?

Comment: It would be the best choice, but I doubt if Qt allows doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested earlier, try to play sound in another thread. But QSound has not enough signals to control it. If you want get deeper control you can use [QSoundEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html) Try this:

header:

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0);


signals:

public slots:
    void process();

};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

Cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QSound>

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Worker::process()
{
    QSound *sound = new QSound("path");
    sound->setLoops(100);
    sound->play();
}
```

Usage:

```
QThread *thr = new QThread;
Worker * work = new Worker;
connect(thr, SIGNAL(started()), work, SLOT(process()));
work->moveToThread(thr);
thr->start();
```

To play it several minutes you can set infinite number of loops and use `QTimer` (maybe `singleShot`) to end thread and delete object(music will be stopped too).